# iOS8 : running in the background for forever : GameCenter

Tags: ios, game-center

I know this may seem a duplicate subject but its not (hopefully its not)

We have an application that uses GameCenter in the background for backend communication, up until ios8, GameCenter has ran in the background fine.

Now I need to find a fix around this, the key is that the app needs to constantly run in the background, it uses GameCenter chat server etc, so we have enabled Audio.  I can't see us being able to use VOIP as an option (Apple would probably reject it)

I tried

```
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(keepAlive) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        [application setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler: ^{
           [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(keepAlive) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
             //[[GCHelper sharedInstance] applicationWentBackground];
        }];

    - (void)keepAlive {

        self.bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            NSLog(@"Background handler called. Not running background tasks anymore.");
    //        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
    //        self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

            [self keepAlive];
        }];
    }
```

Which keeps it going for a bit, **I guess the main question is, is it even possible now?**

I have also followed this guide

http://blog.dkaminsky.info/2013/01/27/keep-your-ios-app-running-in-background-forever/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the app itself is in the foreground, you can fire a notification every xx seconds which handles the background tasks.

When the full app goes into background, you only have a limited amount of time to close actions.

Comment: The app will be in the background

Comment: When the app is in background, you may only close running tasks. Or use the platform notification systems.

Comment: So your saying its now impossible

Comment: I'm unsure what you are exactly trying do while the app is in background. Certain actions are allowed triggered by the platform notification system. So you can have a look at that.

Comment: It creates a server that other apps use

Comment: When other routines communicate using the Notification system, you'll have the opportunity to perform small tasks.

Comment: Have you got any examples of what you are refering to

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html